# Is there a way to make "holes" for parameters in bash commands that can then be "filled" at the end? eg "cp [hole] dir < [arg]" so arg comes at end?

Tags: shell

I'm not sure that the above makes sense, but a pattern I've noticed a lot in my shell usage is the following

I have a command which might be rather long, and due to the design of the CLI, there is a required order. I need to run the command multiple times, often varying a particular argument. of course if I know all the arguments up front I can use xargs or something, but sometimes that isn't the case... so I might have a command like

cli -flag -flag X arg arg arg arg

and rerunning it is annoying because I have to hop back to X. so what would be cool is to somehow do the following:

cli -flag -flag HOLE arg arg arg arg < X

that way if I want to alter the argument, I can press up and easily replace X

is this possible?

Comment: For that particular case of `cp`, the GNU version has the `-t` option to give the target directory, so you can do `cp -t dst files...`, instead of `cp files... dst`. Also for GNU tools, the ability to give options at the end can also help. But it's not generic, of course.

Answer (score 1):

> if I know all the arguments up front I can use xargs or something, but sometimes that isn't the case

If you know all the arguments *except* the one that changes, make a function of it:

```
myfunc () { cli -flag -flag "$1" arg arg arg arg ; }
```

Then call that function with the changing argument.

Or you can use [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction):

```
$ cli -flag -flag X arg arg arg arg    # Run the first time
$ ^X^Y            # will replace the first occurrence of X anywhere in the previous command with Y and run it
$ ^Y^Y2           # now replace Y with Y2 in the command that resulted from the above
```

Note that the history expansion doesn't discriminate - if you had `my-command asterisk period comma colon` and wanted to run `my-command asterisk period apostrophe colon`, you can't use `^comma^apostrophe` because that will produce `my-apostrophend asterisk period comma colon`. A function would be better in this case.

Comment: thank you for the response! I guess what I want is an anonymous function, basically. something like \x { cli -flag -flag $x arg arg arg ; }(ACTUALX). I suppose I could make a func any time I want to do this, but it would just be a useful thing to do arbitrarily for any function, I've had it come up when I was just working randomly with various commands, but not necessarily ones that needed to be made into a full command

Comment: @AQuestionAsker You could do something like `bash -c 'cli -flag -flag "$1" arg arg arg arg' bash X` (where "X" will get subbed in for `$1`), but it seems like more work than it's worth (and the extra level of quoting around the command can get confusing).

Comment: @AQuestionAsker [zsh has anonymous functions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions), but like Gordon, I think it's not worth it. If you're writing that much, you might as well make up a name and have a proper function.